# Word VBA - Aligning Table Column to Top Not Working With wdCellAlignVerticalTop

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

I am trying to automatically align some cells in a Word table.

Here is my code:

```
    Selection.SelectCell
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    Selection.cells.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalTop
```

The text is aligned to the Center but it won't align to the top. I know, you're not supposed to use Selection much - just using this simple example to present the topic in a simple way.

I can align the text using the tools in the "Layout" section. I recorded a Macro doing just that but the recorded Macro doesn't work either. I have also tried to do it using a Range.

EDIT:
As per your request, here is what I am getting vs. what I am trying to achieve:
[image: What I am getting]
[image: What I am trying]

Comment: For me the code works. Maybe show us your outcome and what you expect

Comment: I have added them just now :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```vb
Sub centerVerticalHorizontal(c As Cell)

With c
    .VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalTop
    .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
End With

End Sub
```

You can call the sub like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim tbl As Table
Set tbl = ThisDocument.Tables(1)

centerVerticalHorizontal tbl.Cell(2, 3)   ' row 2, column 3

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, this didn't work for me... I am not able to change the vertical Alignment

Comment: Are there any merged cells or rows?